# Zsh remove keybindings in a keymap

Tags: zsh

Im using the vi mode and there some bindings clashing so I want to remove them.
I tried doing that with `bindkey "+" ""` but it didn't work since the binding is in the keymap: `vicmd`, which is not active.
The man for `zle` doesn't metion anything about deleting bindings inside a map either.

So how can I delete a keybinding that is a specific keymap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the `vicmd` keymap either by name (`bindkey -M vicmd ...`) or with the `-a` option.

To unbind the key, you can use the `-r` option.

```
bindkey -ar "+"
```

or

```
bindkey -M vicmd -r "+"
```

Comment: it worked, thank you. I did not know I could chain the options.